# ALB -> HAPROXY Websocket connection isn't working

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, haproxy, aws-application-load-balancer

Posting in the community after a very long time. I am trying to setup a infrastructure like this.

ALB -> HAPROXY ec2 node -> Webserver.

I am able to successfully launch the application and access it via http and https.

I am trying to simply proxy the websocket request to the demo echo test application but it fails.
I verified the Haproxy configs, looks good to me but nothing works.

Here is Haproxy config.

```
defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend http-traffic
        bind *:80
        acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
        redirect scheme https if is_websocket
        use_backend websocket if is_websocket
        default_backend tomcat

frontend https-traffic
        bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/mydomain.pem
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
        acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
        use_backend websocket if is_websocket
        default_backend tomcat

frontend health
    bind *:8080
    acl backend_dead nbsrv(tomcat) lt 1
    monitor-uri /haproxy_status
    monitor fail if backend_dead

backend tomcat
        reqirep ^([^\ :]*)\ /(.*)       \1\ /ImageServlet\2
        server app-i-0000000000f x.x.x.x:8080 cookie app-i-0000000000f check
        server app-i-0000000000f x.x.x.x:8080 cookie app-i-0000000000f check

backend websocket
    http-request set-header Host demos.kaazing.com
    http-request set-path /echo
    server ws demos.kaazing.com:443/echo ssl verify none
```

Appreciate your help. Thanks